# Como implementar um Controller Abstrato que executa as actions implementadas em controllers concretos, dependendo das variáveis passadas via params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Preciso de um controller abstrato para redirecionar a execução das actions "create" e "show" implementadas em módulos, de acordo com valores repassados via params, ex.:

```
    class Indicator::AbstractController < ApplicationController

    # é aqui que não funciona
    # sei que aqui é a definição da classe, portanto não dá para 
    # utilizar as variáveis de instancia

      include ConcreteController1 if params[:resource_type_id].eql?(1)
      include ConcreteController2 if params[:resource_type_id].eql?(2)


      #não implementa method/action create
      #não implementa method/action show

      # já tentei implementar as actions create e view e redirecionar a execução para 
      # os módulos concretos, mas não consegui.
    end

    Module ConcreteController1
      def create
        # metodo de criação especial para o controller1
      end

      def show
        # view especial para o controller1
      end
    end


    Module ConcreteController2
      def create
        # metodo de criação especial para o controller2
      end

      def show
        # view especial para o controller2
      end
    end
```

Já tentei converter os módulos em classes ConcreteController < ApplicationController e fazer o redirecionamento via routes mas também tive dificuldades pois o número de controllers concretos é variável.

Estamos em uma aplicação legada em Rails 3.2

Answer (score 2):

Talvez você consiga isso usando constraints na rota
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints
Alguma coisa parecida com:

```
get '/users/{id}', action: 'show' controller: "my_controller1", constraints: lambda { |request| request[:resource_type_id] == 1 }  
get '/users/{id}', action: 'show' controller: "my_controller2", constraints: lambda { |request| request[:resource_type_id] == 2 }
```

Código não testado (sintaxe provavelmente errada) mas a ideia é essa

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso, eu usaria uma classe responsável por saber redirecionar para ação desejada a partir dos parametros.

```
concrete_action = ConcreteAction.new( params )
concrete_action.execute_create
concrete_action.execute_show
```

no seu controller ficaria

```
class Indicator::AbstractController < ApplicationController

def create
  concrete_action = ConcreteAction.new( params )
  resultado = concrete_action.execute_create
  redirect_to 'algum path'
end

end
```

Porém, uma boa sugestão é buscar sobre Use Case Controller e outros padrões arquiteturais. Uma abordagem um pouco diferente do que você está tentando, mas acho que vai te ajudar também.

- Use Case Controller - Craig Larman
- https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html
- GRASP PATTERNS

Answer (score 0):

Cara eu não sei se dá para fazer o que vc deseja dessa forma. Você até pode ter herança nos controllers, mas não dessa forma que você descreveu em cima.

Na verdade para dar uma ajuda mais concreta eu precisava saber qual é o seu problema. Talvez os controllers dinamicos não seja a solução para o problema.